Blazor Server using MSAL auth. Error connecting to API: Cannot provide a value for property 'downstreamAPI'
I'm in a world of pain here. For weeks now I've simply being trying to use AD B2C or Entra to provide authentication for my Blazor and Maui apps and my secure API. I tried to set up a Blazor Server app in the following way:

Create new ASP.NET Core Web API project in VS 2022. Select .NET 8, authentication "Microsoft Identity Platform" and let VS set it all up.

Create new Blazor Server app in .NET 7. Select the same Entra tenant etc that was created in the previous step. Select that I want to use the above API project. Let VS set it all up.

When I run these two projects, I can log in to the Blazor Server app using my Microsoft details but when I call the API I get this:


System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'downstreamAPI' 
on type 'Kae.BlazorServer4.Pages.CallWebApi'. 
There is no registered service of type 
'Microsoft.Identity.Web.IDownstreamWebApi'.

Now I know roughly what this error means. There's a problem with dependency injection and it can't find this type. But I can't figure out how to fix it. Surely these templates should work out of the box? What am I doing wrong here?

IDownstreamWebApi is used for generating Access token to call the secured API. By default, you will have
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))

in your blazor server application Program.cs when you used the VS template, it allows you to sign in with your Microsoft account into your application, but it hasn't provided the option for you to call Azure AD secured web API.
We need to have
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

so that it provides ITokenAcquisition service to generate access token.
@using Microsoft.Identity.Web
@inject ITokenAcquisition TokenAcquisitionService

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var token = await TokenAcquisitionService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://client_id/Tiny.Greet" });
    }
}


If you are concerned about api://client_id/api_permission_name, you might take a look at this seris of tutorial about how to expose an API by Azure AD and use it to protect web API. By the way, you are created the project with VS template which provides with you a sample code integrate Azure AD b2b, but you mentioned you are trying to use Azure AD b2c. I wanna say that they are similar with each other but still have some differences, e.g. b2c needs to create custom policy for sign in/up.

It seems like you have not registered given service in Program.cs file. Try adding below relevant lines and check.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});


builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler(); 
builder.Services.AddBlazorBootstrap();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

